# Pandas's data frame fails to show non-english alphabet from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf

I have a `CSV` file which contain some latin information. But when I save it in a data frame, it doesn't show the Latin alphabets.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=",", header=None, encoding="utf-16")
```

Some lines of 'CSV' file are as following:

```
NAME, X, Y
Peñuelas,18.026618,PR
Quebradillas,18.466357,PR
Rincón,18.340562,PR
```

and what is shown in df are `?` instead of those Latin alphabet.

```
Pe?uelas,18.026618,PR
Quebradillas,18.466357,PR
Rinc?n,18.340562,PR
```

I have used **encoding="utf-16"**, **encoding="utf-8"**, **encoding="latin-1"** and they didn't work.

When I print a value from NAME column of my data frame it gives the following:

```
df['NAME'][20]
Out[253]: 'San Sebasti\xc3\xa1n'
```

Which should be **San Sebastián**

Now what should I do to show these non-english correctly?

Also `abbr['NAME'][3208] == 'San Sebasti?n'` gives **True** and 
`'San Sebasti\xc3\xa1n' == 'San Sebasti?n'` returns **False**. I cannot understand why the former one is True.

Comment: isn't `utf-8` more common than `utf-16`?

Comment: Thanks for responding. But I've used utf-8 as well and it didn't work.

Comment: I was just curious since you didn't mention `utf-8`. Also, I think `latin-1` is pretty common in Europe as well. See more [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html).

Comment: `latin-1` is not working. My dataset just contain Latin alphabet other than English and I'm wondering why it is not working.